# Why declare class' properties when constructor initialize this properties

Tags: php, oop

Write what is best and why?

```
class Chat
{
    private $_couleur;
    private $_race;

    function __construct($couleur, $race)
    {
        $this->_couleur = $couleur;
        $this->_race = "$race";
    }

    public function getCouleur() {
        return $this->_couleur;
    }
}
```

Or

```
class Chat
{
    function __construct($couleur, $race)
    {
        $this->_couleur = $couleur;
        $this->_race = "$race";
    }

    public function getCouleur() {
        return $this->_couleur;
    }
}
```

Because `$this->_couleur` is initialized when the class is instancied, so declare the property directly in the class is useless, isn't ?

Comment: Declaring the property isn't useless..... in the first example, it's defined as private, so you're specifying a visibility; in the second case, it's being defined dynamically as public.... you can also document the properties if they're defined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declaring the variables at the top of your class is a very good practice, because it makes it clear to anyone that reads your code which properties the class has **private** and which properties the class has **public**.

In the second example your variables will be public because they're dynamically generated.

When your constructor would be much bigger it is a pain in the ass as developer to find out where your variables are introduced.
It is also good to set default values (if they are always the same) to the variables in the class as opposed to the constructor. It makes your code more readable and understandable.

Comment: Where you set the values really depends on the values you want to set though. In the OP's case, they are passed to the constructor as arguments, so it would not be possible or even make sense to assign them their values outside of the constructor.

Comment: That is why I said: "if they are always the same". So yes I agree. If there is a clear initial value which is always assigned then set them directly, otherwise in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

First block of code is better from the second, But one thing in  first block.

Objects of the same type will have access to each others private and protected members even though they are not the same instances. This is because the implementation specific details are already known when inside those objects.

This code collected from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

```
<?php
class Test
{
    private $foo;

    public function __construct($foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    private function bar()
    {
        echo 'Accessed the private method.';
    }

    public function baz(Test $other)
    {
        // We can change the private property:
        $other->foo = 'hello';
        var_dump($other->foo);

        // We can also call the private method:
        $other->bar();
    }
}

$test = new Test('test');

$test->baz(new Test('other'));
?>
```

**Output:**

> string(5) "hello"
>   Accessed the private method.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is better. You are actually declaring your variables as private, giving them a meaningful scope. The second version is more error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add one simple benefit of declaring class properties: Any good IDE will parse and build a symbol table out of your declared class properties. So if you are writing a class and start typing `$this->`, a list of your declared properties will show up so you can easily select the one you want to use. If you create variables in your constructor without declaring them, your IDE won't be able to see them.